# Windows 7, JDK 1.8, Spring Boot application JAR takes up lot of time for method Security.getProviders() to return

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am executing a Spring Boot application which takes up lot of time to create a SSL context.

Initial debugging points to method `Security.getProviders()` not returning the list of providers for around 8 minutes.

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
```

This happens when I execute the JAR using below command on command prompt. But it does not take time when executed as Java Application via Eclipse of STS.

"Command to run Application"

```
java -DkeystoreFile=<Certificate File Name> -DkeystorePassword=<Password> -jar aws-sqs-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar <QueueName> localhost false <proxy IP> <proxy Port>
```

Maven Pom.xml, uses spring boot maven plugin to build the application:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Did you try a simple "Hello World" style program to test `Security.getProviders()`? E.g. `public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Security.getProviders())); }` Try it with and without the `-D` arguments.

Comment: Yes i did try this and it works pretty fast even when i execute it on command line.

Comment: But i did place the above code just after the Main function of my Spring boot (maven) application and did a maven clean package and executed the Jar, I get a delay of 8 minutes before Securty.getProviders() finishes.

Comment: So does your Spring Boot app add any extra providers to the classpath?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for the late reply, no my Spring Boot application does not provide extra providers. I printed out the list of providers both in standalone application and in Spring boot , both are same.